# AdonisJS Back-End API File Uploads Failing Because of CORS

Tags: javascript, cors, adonis.js

I am using Docker Compose to bring up two Docker containers:

1. Stock `nginx` container running a WebPacked Vue.js application and listening on port 9090.
2. Stock `node` container running `npm start` inside of an AdonisJS project and listening on port 3333.

The goal is to use AJAX to upload a file from `http://website.com:9090` to `http://website.com:3333` and then send back a success response. Locally in development, CORS is not an issue and all requests are fine. However, when deploying to "production" (or planning for production) I receive the following error in the JS console in Firefox:

`Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
the remote resource at http://lemcoe.nato:3333/uploader. (Reason: CORS
request did not succeed).`

Looking at the Network tab in Firefox, I see both an `OPTIONS` and a `POST` (the request that actually uploads the file) request. The `OPTIONS` request is seemingly successful, and these are the request and response headers to that request: (`lemcoe.nato` is locally pointed to `website.com` using DNS, in this picture)

[image: CORS issue with AdonisJS]

Yet, the file upload never actually occurs. Here are the headers to the POST request that never received a response:

[image: Unsuccessful POST request's headers.]

Here is AdonisJS' `config/cors.js` configuration file:

```
module.exports = {
    origin: '*',
    methods: ['GET', 'HEAD', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'POST', 'DELETE'],
    headers: true,
    exposeHeaders: false,
    credentials: false,
    maxAge: 90
}
```

I have tried every combination of those settings that I can think of, and I have done everything I can to ensure that all ports are being properly mapped in Docker. Yet, still, all web browsers display a CORS error when attempting to execute the file uploads to the back-end container.

Where should I start in order to debug this issue? I believe the project's response to the initial `OPTIONS` request is a satisfactory one, but I must be missing something when it comes to the second step of this process. What I find interesting is that when the same exact code is run locally on the same ports but without Docker, everything functions as expected and CORS is never mentioned in the console. Only when the two projects are isolated on the same Docker host (with the same ports and domains) does the CORS issue become an issue.

Thanks!

Comment: As far as the response to the OPTIONS, yes, based on the request headers and response headers shown in the question, the OPTIONS preflight is successful. If it weren’t, your browser would stop and never sent the POST from your code. But since it does send that POST, you can know for certain that the OPTIONS preflight did in fact succeed.

Comment: You say that the browser never even receives the response to the POST once it does send it — but the *“Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource…”* error seems to indicate otherwise. That error appears to be the browser saying, I got a response (to the POST) but I can’t expose it to your frontend code. The main (maybe only) reason the browser would do that  is if the response to the POST lacks the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header. Just because that header is in the OPTIONS response doesn’t mean it’s also in the POST response.

Comment: So given the above, it seems you probably want to use devtools to see confirm if in fact the browser is getting a response to the POST request, and then check the response headers to see if Access-Control-Allow-Origin is in there or not. If it’s not, then the CORS config on that  `http://lemcoe.nato:3333/uploader` endpoint needs to be changed to send it.